# org.testng.TestNGException: Parameter 'browser' is required by @Configuration on method MethodSetup

Tags: selenium

**ENV:** Seleniuim web driver, testng, eclipse, java 1.8

I have a test. I can run it just fine from testng suite (right click suite > run as > testng suite). If I run the test directly (right click the test > run as > testng test), i get an error:

> org.testng.TestNGException:  Parameter 'browser' is required by
>   @Configuration on method MethodSetup but has not been marked @Optional
>   or defined in
>   C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1694993462\testng-customsuite.xml

BaseTest:

```
public class BaseTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;

    @Parameters ({"browser"})
    @BeforeMethod
    protected void MethodSetup(String browser){
        System.out.println("method set up");
        driver = Browsers.getDriver(browser);
        }
//....
}
```

Test:

```
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest{

    @Parameters({ "browser" , "ch" })   
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Test
    public void positiveLoginTest(){


        String expectedPageTitle = "Seeker Dashboard - Profile";
        String Expectedprofilename = "md";
//...
}
```

TestNG suite:

```
<suite name="TestAll">

                <test name="ie1">
        <parameter name="browser" value="ch"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.dice.LoginTest">
            <methods>
                    <include name="positiveLoginTest"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>


</suite>
```

---

[image]

Comment: i solved this problem going to run configurations and setting them properly manaully.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying  as a parameter in your suite xml. When you run as suite, that particular xml is used. But when you select a single test and run it, testng creates a custom testng file (with bare minimums - no parameters, no listeners - you can take a look at the file on the path that you mention).

You need to specify your xml as a template xml in eclipse if that is a standard xml that you use. Go to project properties -> testng -> Set the xml as a template xml.

Comment: I am not sure If I was able to follow you. I right click project > properties > browse the xml file  in template xml file > click apply. I still get same error when I run the particular test. XML file runs just fine.

Comment: Simply run you testclass from *.xml file (right click on *.xml -> Run). Parameterized test can't be run directly

Comment: @Drupol When you trigger using eclipse as a single test, the testng suite level params are only utilized to create the custom testng suite. So you need to declare your parameter outside your test tag. Else you need to run by right-clicking on your xml file and then clicking on run as testng suite.

Comment: I must be able to run the tests directly by right click on test > select testng Test. I already added parameters before test:     @Parameters({ "browser" , "ch" })   
. How can I declare parameter outside test?

Comment: @anshulGupta I am having the same issue. I was able to run parameterized tests directly in the past (3 months ago).

Comment: @anshulGupta in addition, doing so from the testng.xml file won't allow me to run a test in debug mode.